# getting numscroller to work only when an element is in the users viewpoint

Tags: jquery

i was just trying out this plugin online , its called jQuery `numscroller` , now i made a very simple demo here .

HTML ::

```
<div class="numscroller" data-delay="2" data-increment="9" data-min="0" data-max="1024">0</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
        margin-top: 2500px;
        font-size: 5em;
    }
```

notice how data-attibutes are used for the plugin to initialize , have a loook at the **[FIDDLE HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/8yppf52L/1/)**

now i went through the demo page and the doc's have the following to say :

> numscroller is a small JQuery counter plugin used to count up towards
>   a specified number when the number is scrolled into view.

i am able to get the counter to work , but the problem is that the increment does't start when the element is in viewpoint but rather when the page loads .

can somebody explain this discripency ?

[here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Plugin-For-Counting-Up-Numbers-While-Scrolling-numscroller.html) is a helpful tut i found about the plugin .

how do i make the counter to start only when the elements is in the users view point .

Thank you. 
Alex-z.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working with `Margin` but it is working if we've used `<br>`..

I have tried and here is the [fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/8yppf52L/2/)

Sorry, it's very long after you asked but helpful for other people who face the same..